# How to split a string angularjs n times

Tags: angularjs, split

I am using AngularJs.
I have a string say:

```
$scope.myString = "hello stack. \n how are you? \n what do you need? \n blah blah blah";
```

I want to divide this string every time I find \n.
So the output (on my html page) must be like:

```
hello stack
how are you?
what do you need?
blah blah blah
```

*number of times \n appears may differ*

Comment: Please show what you have tried and identify the specific problems you are having

Comment: Kindly put some effort in googling your answer...

Comment: could not find this on google. sry

Answer (score 1):

```
    $scope.myString = "hello stack. \n how are you? \n what do you need? \n blah blah blah";
    var result = $scope.myString.split("\n").join("");
```